# How to increase the size of /dev?

Tags: mount, udev

I have run into a rather unusual situation:

```
...
cp: failed to extend ‘/dev/mapper/loop0p1’: No space left on device

nathan@nathan-desktop:~$ df
Filesystem                        1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev                                4017004   4017004          0 100% /dev
```

I have run out of "disk" space on `/dev`. (For the curious, I am using `kpartx` to copy some partition images to a disk image.)

There is no entry for `/dev` in `/etc/fstab` - how do I change the amount of space allocated for `/dev`? Is there a configuration file I can modify?

Comment: Maybe this might help?  http://superuser.com/a/675664/440143

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As given in [this Super User post](https://superuser.com/a/675664/334516), remounting it works:

```
$ df -h | grep udev
udev                                      1.0G  4.0K  1.0G   1% /dev
$ sudo mount -o remount,size=3G /dev
$ df -h | grep udev                 
udev                                      3.0G  4.0K  3.0G   1% /dev
```